# Context is not working on Glide when I extends Application on android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, applicationcontext, android-glide

Hi in my project I'm using Glide lib for loading image from server, same code was working fine but when I extend my class to Application for global context I'm getting error

My global class for context

```
public class GlobalAppContextSingleton extends Application {
private static GlobalAppContextSingleton mInstance;
private Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    GlobalAppContextSingleton.getInstance().initialize(this);
}
public static GlobalAppContextSingleton getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null) mInstance = getSync();
    return mInstance;
}

private static synchronized GlobalAppContextSingleton getSync() {
    if (mInstance == null) mInstance =
            new GlobalAppContextSingleton();
    return mInstance;
}

public void initialize(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public Context getApplicationContext() {
    return context;
}}
```

In my AndroidManifest class

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:name=".GlobalAppContextSingleton"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

    >
    <activity
        android:name=".Activitys.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>
```

This is the fragment where I'm using the Glide lib for pic loading from server

```
 public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {


    public ProfileFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    TextView profile_txt_firstname,profile_txt_lastname,profile_txt_role;
    ImageView profile_img_profilepic;
    Context context;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        preferenceData preference= new preferenceData(GlobalAppContextSingleton.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
        profile_txt_firstname=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.profile_txt_firstname);
        profile_txt_lastname=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.profile_txt_lastname);
        profile_img_profilepic=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.profile_img_profilepic);

        profile_txt_firstname.setText(preference.getString("FirstName"));
        profile_txt_lastname.setText(preference.getString("LastName"));

        String pic =preference.getString("ProfilePicture");
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(pic, Base64.DEFAULT);
        //Glide.with(GlobalAppContextSingleton.getInstance().getApplicationContext())
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(decodedString)
                .asBitmap()
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .into(profile_img_profilepic);
//        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
//        profile_img_profilepic.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context=context;
    }
}
```

Error I'm getting is

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.airbustask, PID: 22813
Theme: themes:{}
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.cache.MemorySizeCalculator.<init>(MemorySizeCalculator.java:35)
at com.bumptech.glide.GlideBuilder.createGlide(GlideBuilder.java:177)
at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.get(Glide.java:155)
at com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager.<init>(RequestManager.java:62)
at com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager.<init>(RequestManager.java:53)
at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.supportFragmentGet(RequestManagerRetriever.java:198)
at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:104)
at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:87)
at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:629)
at com.maintainsmart.Fragments.ProfileFragment.onCreateView(ProfileFragment.java:57)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1632)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:637)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:166)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1237)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1085)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1611)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1458)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:746)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1458)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:746)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2905)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2108)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1224)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1115)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6023)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
    at android.view.Ch
```

Please help me on this what wrong I've done here

Comment: `context` is not initialized when Glide calls it. Just pass `GlobalAppContextSingleton.getInstance().getApplicationContext()` into `Glide.with()`.

Comment: I did that but till now I'm getting same error  Glide.with(GlobalAppContextSingleton.getInstance().getApplicationContext())

Comment: if I remove  android:name=".GlobalAppContextSingleton" in AndroidManifest the code work fine but I don't know why is not working when I add the application class

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry I didn't look through your code more closely the first time around. Please don't remove that from the manifest. I think your problem exists because you're initializing your `Application` class with a `new`. Try `if (mInstance == null) mInstance = this;` inside `getSync()`? If it works, I'll post an answer with an explanation and you can accept it. :P

Comment: it says this can't be referenced from a static context

Comment: Hmm. Remove `GlobalAppContextSingleton.getInstance().initialize(this);` from onCreate and put `if (context==null) context = this;`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `getActivity()` you are in fragment.

```
 Glide.with(context)
                .load(decodedString)
                .asBitmap()
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .into(profile_img_profilepic);
```

change to

```
 Glide.with(getActivity())
                .load(decodedString)
                .asBitmap()
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                 .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(profile_img_profilepic);
```

**Update** Add `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)`

```
  Glide.with(getActivity())
                    .load(decodedString)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(profile_img_profilepic);
```

Comment: @SohailZahid would you mind explaining why this works? thanks!

Comment: @androidtitan because context is not initialized in there example getActivity() give you context on activity but these days with updated version of glide you can pass this in glide in fragment too.